# Remote debug kotlin code via IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, remote-debugging

There's an app written in Java & Kotlin. I'm running that in debug mode. The debugger gets attached correctly. If my breakpoint is set in Java code it's hit but any breakpoint in Kotlin code isn't. Why is that? How to make it work in IntelliJ?

Both types of sources reside in src/main.

Actually there is an answser to this question at StackOverflow. This might be marked as a duplicate of [Intellij IDEA debugger not working on Gradle Vert.X project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42716493/intellij-idea-debugger-not-working-on-gradle-vert-x-project)

Comment: Please show your code or even better provide simple project where it's reproduced for you.

Comment: Also make sure that your codebase is in sync with what you are debugging and if you are using lambdas (often confusing when multiple scope layers are on a single line) that you configure the break point to something inside the lambda.