# @ConfigurationProperties Spring Boot Configuration Annotation Processor not found in classpath

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I try to make completion for custom properties in *Spring Boot*.

I tried to create a simple project via *IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3*:

1. Created a new Gradle project with *Spring Boot Initializer* (I haven't checked anything at all).
2. Created a new class `Properties`.

When I annotated it with `@ConfigurationProperties`, the next notification has appeared:
[image: notification]

[The documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) said that I should add the following to my project:

```
dependencies {
    optional "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}

compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
```

After that, I tried to rebuild the project and enable annotation processors in settings but the notification hasn't gone. Completion doesn't work too (I created a string `my`).

Comment: What Gradle version do you use? Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42588061/104891) help?

Comment: Now it works, but I forgot to add `propdeps-plugin`, so I cannot be sure if the new version of the IDE is the solution. Anyway, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I had the same problem. I use idea 2017.2 and gradle 4.1, 
and some blog said you should add:

```
dependencies {
    optional "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}
```

But I changed it to this:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}
```

And the warning is gone.

Comment: This issue kept bugging me for months now. I tried rest of the answers, but nothing worked. This worked somehow. Running on Gradle 5.2.1 and IDEA 2018.3.5

Comment: @k9yosh for Gradle 5.2.1 prefer [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53233859/1429387)

Answer (score 44):

According to the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor), the correct configuration since Gradle 4.6 is

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    // ...
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA supports `annotationProcessor` scope since build 193.3382 (2019.3). Don't forget to enable [annotation processing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html) in IntelliJ IDEA settings.

Answer (score 44):

For those who are using maven, Intellij was still not happy with the addition of dependency. Seems like adding `annotationProcessorPaths` via `maven-compiler-plugin` finally tamed the beast.

Make sure the `version` matches your spring dependencies. I suspect it would be already present in your effective POM.

**Reason**: I was using a custom parent-pom which had a mapstruct annotation processor set in `annotationProcessorPaths` and that actually triggered IntelliJ to ask for all other annotation processors to be specified manually as well.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
          <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </path>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: apparently mapstruct requires that we specifically mention mapstruct in ``annotationProcessorPaths`` , and when we start specifying them manually, we must add spring-boot-configuration-processor, lombok, etc manually as well. At least that's what intellij wanted

Comment: Thanks for this! Intellij shows a [link to the spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) when it shows the error but there's no mention of configuring annotationProcessorPaths in maven-compiler-plugin

Comment: Please do not use hard-coded version in Maven. Inherit, so you need to change only once when upgrading SpringBoot: <version>${project.parent.version}</version>

Comment: My parent project is not spring boot parent POM. So that is a bit of YMMV.

Answer (score 27):

For those using Maven or Gradle, just add the dependency on *spring-boot-configuration-processor*.

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle 4.5 and earlier**

```
dependencies {
     compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}
```

**Gradle 4.6 and later**

```
dependencies {
      annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}
```

For more information:
**"Generating Your Own Metadata by Using the Annotation Processor"**
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor

Answer (score 20):

It happens to me for two reasons in IDEA:

1. Double check if your setting is picked (enabled) in IDEA: Preferences->Annotation Processors->Enable annotation processing.
2. After update your Idea, check your plugins and update them. It happens that plugins become incompatible with your new IDEA version, so just click to update them.

Comment: In my IDEA, (1) is : File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Annotation Processors

Answer (score 11):

I forgot to add [propdeps-plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin). However, I remember that it didn't work for me even with the plugin on 2016.3, So as @CrazyCoder mentioned, try to downgrade Gradle or download the new 2017.1 version ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587487/noclassdeffounderror-after-intellij-idea-upgrade/42588061#42588061)).
Also you may receive `Re-run Spring Boot Configuration Annotation Processor to update generated metadata` when you will solve this issue. For this, click `Refresh all Gradle projects` (in Gradle side menu).

Comment: Still not working for me. I added the `propdeps-plugin`, the `optional` line and `compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)`, got IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3. Tried running `clean` task in Gradle, then `Refresh all` and `Build`, still nothing. Any idea?

Answer (score 10):

In maven project helps adding dependency spring-boot-configuration-processor and marking main class with @EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class).

Maybe somebody helps.

Answer (score 7):

In version 2018.3 of IntelliJ, I solved this problem (as per [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor)) in the following way:

> With Gradle 4.5 and earlier, the dependency should be declared in the
>   compileOnly configuration, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>   compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
> }
> ```
>
> With Gradle 4.6 and later, the dependency should be declared in the
>   annotationProcessor configuration, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>   annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 7):

For Kotlin projects, the working configuration since Gradle 4.6 is using annotation processor

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

dependencies {
    kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:$springBootVersion")
    compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:$springBootVersion")
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your comment I managed to generate the meta file as well, but unfortunately IntelliJ is not picking it up. I found a [related issue in jetbrains bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15040). Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 4):

You have to mention in the main class the class you want to use @ConfigurationProperties annotation like below.

```java
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
```

The Property Configuration class with @ConfigurationProperties will be like this

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;


@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class AppProperties {
    String name;
    String id;
}
```

The Main class will be like this

```java
import com.auth2.demo.config.AppProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ version 2018.1.2. I also had to define the actual version of spring-boot-configuration-processor in order to get it worked:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.0.1.RELEASE')
```

Comment: For me it was `compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:$springVersion"`

Answer (score 0):

following works for me:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/' }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE"
    }
}

...

apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-eclipse'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'

...

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor" // for @ConfigurationProperties, make sure compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
    ...
}

compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor), the correct configuration for Gradle 4.5 and earlier is

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring's website has a tutorial that contains a great explanation how to make it work. Just follow the steps under "Configuration properties" section below.

It has one of the steps which none of other answers mentioned here:
run `./gradlew kaptKotlin` manually.

As of Mar 2021, IDEA will still show the warning on top of the Kotlin properties class, but the properties will be recognized and work. You'll be able to navigate from `.properties` file to the Kotlin properties class, but not the other way around.

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/  scroll down to "Configuration properties" part.

Or the same page on GitHub:

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-kotlin/blob/master/README.adoc#configuration-properties

Answer (score 0):

This error can be resolved by adding this annotation in your mainApplicaitonClass

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({class name}.class)
```