# How to configure for Spring Boot Configuration Annotation Processor using @ConfigurationProperties on IntelliJ?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, annotation-processing

[image: Warning]

On IntelliJ, I am getting a **Spring Boot Configuration Annotation Processor not configured** for having @ConfigurationProperties. Below is my class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
@Data
@RefreshScope
class Config {
    String propA;
    String propB;
    ...
}
```

I am not sure what's causing this and when I click on the wrench for settings, I do not see any options to configure for metadata files.

Comment: ...but does it break the application when you run it, though?  I see this error often enough in IntelliJ and it hasn't posed an issue for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@ConfigurationProperties Spring Boot Configuration Annotation Processor not found in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839126/configurationproperties-spring-boot-configuration-annotation-processor-not-foun)

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same problem with `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2` and `Maven 3.6.2`. The solution was to explicitly set the annotation processor in the `maven-compiler-plugin` settings. I found the answer here:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48028193/9989732
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64031211/9989732

The full configuration:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
      </path>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.8</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

I resolved it by adding the following dependency to my pom file

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily generate your own configuration meta-data file from items annotated with @ConfigurationProperties by using the spring-boot-configuration-processor jar. The jar includes a Java annotation processor which is invoked as your project is compiled. To use the processor, simply include spring-boot-configuration-processor as an optional dependency, for example with Maven you would add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

For **Gradle**, like Maven, we need to add The appropriate `annotation processor`. To do so, add a line to the `dependencies` section in your `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:'
    ...
}
```