# Error when trying to run demos in a gradle project in IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

I cloned this repository https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX

Everything was building fine and intellJ wasn't complaining.

Then I tried to run the CloneDemo in intelliJ (included the arguments) and this is happened. Any ideas?

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fxmisc/richtext/InlineCssTextArea
    at org.fxmisc.richtext.demo.CloneDemo.start(CloneDemo.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

```
intelliJ java arguments

    -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.5\bin"

    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

    -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\charsets.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\deploy.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\javaws.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jce.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfr.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jsse.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\management-agent.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\plugin.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\resources.jar
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar
        C:\Users\username\projects\TestingRandomThings\RichTextFX\richtextfx-demos\build\classes\main
        C:\Users\username\projects\TestingRandomThings\RichTextFX\richtextfx-demos\build\resources\main
        C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.5\lib\idea_rt.jar"

    com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain

    org.fxmisc.richtext.demo.CloneDemo
```

The gradle script for the demo module builds a fatJar. But this is not being used by intelliJ. When running the program with the jar it runs without issues.

```
java -cp build/libs/richtextfx-demos-fat-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.fxmisc.richtext.demo.CloneDemo
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42588061/104891.

Answer (score 0):

The issue still stands, but [JordanMartinez](https://github.com/JordanMartinez) showed me a way around it. With the newest version of intelliJ (2016.3+), one can assign the building process to gradle. And gradle can run the classes for you, as shown in [this article](https://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/gradle-goodness-delegate-build-and-run.html).