# Spring Boot Devtools do not work with Gradle when declared as optional dependency

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-management, spring-boot-devtools

Following the documentation I decided to use `optional` scope for Devtools using special propdeps plugin for Gradle:

> Flagging the dependency as optional is a best practice that prevents devtools from being transitively applied to other modules using your project. Gradle does not support optional dependencies out-of-the-box so you may want to have a look to the propdeps-plugin in the meantime.

What I add to my `build.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'

dependencies {
    optional('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
}
```

and it does not seem to work at all.

At first, it breaks the ability to run `@SpringBootApplication` main method from Intellij (the problem was already described here: [IntelliJ fails to start Spring Boot/Gradle application when using Spring Boot developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016574/intellij-fails-to-start-spring-boot-gradle-application-when-using-spring-boot-de)). But I can still start the app with `bootRun` goal so it is not a big problem if I still want to follow best practice declaring devtools as `optinal`.

The main problem is that it does not work for me at all. I run the app with `bootRun` and then execute `compileJava --rerun-tasks` expecting the app to be reloaded but it will not. Nothing happens. If I try to do the same with Devtools declared as `runtime`, then it performs quick reload without complete jvm restart.

I tried both: latest stable `1.5.7.RELEASE` and the last available `2.0.0.M4`.

Let me know if Devtools works for you when declared as `optional` in Gradle or if you know how to fix `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when running `main` method from IntelliJ and `optional` Devtools?